# Understanding mathematical induction for divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I'm on my quest to understand mathematical induction proofs (beginners). First, thanks to [How to use mathematical induction with inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244097/how-to-use-mathematical-induction-with-inequalities) I kinda understood better the procedure, and practiced it with [Is this induction procedure correct? ($2^n<n!$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245576/is-this-induction-procedure-correct-2nn). It didn't turn out so bad :)

So far I've been doing equalities and inequalities. Alright. When things seemed to get better now I'm asked to prove **divisibility**.

My book has an exercise with the solution, but there is a part I don't get well:

---

> With $n\ge1$ prove:
>
> $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 6.
>
> Assume $$\exists k[n(n+1)(n+2) = 6k]$$ For the inductive step and
>   using distribution: $$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = n(n+1)(n+2)+3(n+1)(n+2)$$
>   $$=6k+3\cdot2k'$$ $$=6(k+k') = 6k''$$

Alright. I see where is that $6k$ coming from, but what about the $3\cdot2k'$? How does the $3(n+1)(n+2)$ we had become that?

---

That's it for the example I didn't understand well. But I also tried doing another exercise by myself (and didn't manage to do it):

Prove, with $n\ge1$:

$10^n+3\cdot4^{n+2}+5$ is divisible by $9$.

First, I prove it for $n+1$:

To do so we need to show that $\exists x[10^1+3\cdot4^{1+2}+5=9x]$. It holds, because $(10^1+3\cdot4^{1+2}+5) = (10+3\cdot16+5) = (15+48) = 63 = 9 \cdot 7$

Now we assume
$$\exists x[10^n+3\cdot4^{n+2}+5=9x]$$

We need to prove it for $n+1$:
$$10^{n+1}+3\cdot4^{n+3} = 10^n\cdot10+3\cdot4^n\cdot4^3$$
$$= 10^n\cdot10+3\cdot4^{n+2}\cdot4$$
$$=(9x-3\cdot4^{n+2}-5)\cdot10+(3\cdot4^{n+2}\cdot4)$$
By this point I don't even know what I'm doing. I though that I could use $10^n$ with the inductive assumption and replace it with $(9x-3\cdot4^{n+2}-5)$, similar to what the book did before. But now the situation looks worse.

---

Similarly to this question [How to use mathematical induction with inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244097/how-to-use-mathematical-induction-with-inequalities), I seek to understand mathematical induction when applied to **divisibility** cases this time. It seems (for me) that all these cases (equalities, inequalities and divisibility) do have important differences at the moment of solving.

Comment: Simply, either $n+1$ or $n+2$ is *even*, consequently, so are their product.

Comment: Compare to this question, which is the same problem, a little disguised http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211121/simple-induction-n3-n-is-divisible-by-6-am-i-doing-it-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler theorem of this type and that brings us the $2k'$: With $n\ge 1$ prove that $n(n+1)$ is amultiple of $2$.

*Remark:* You should now be able to prove with yet another induction that $\frac{(n+k)!}{(n-1)!}=n(n+1)\cdots (n+k)$ is a multiple of $k!$.

---

Your other attempt is fine so far.
Note that $$(9x-3\cdot 4^{n+2}-5)\cdot 10+(3\cdot 4^{n+2}\cdot4) = 90x-18\cdot 4^{n+2}-50\\=9\cdot(10x-2\cdot 4^{n+2}-5)-5.$$

Comment: Question: In your last expression, there is a $-5$ hanging outside. Why is that okay to have? I mean, I though that the objective was to end up with something like $9x$ but now we have $9x-5$. Doesn't that cause problems?

Comment: That's probably because you started with $10^{n+1}+3\cdot 4^{n+3}$ instead of $10^{n+1}+3\cdot 4^{n+3}+5$. Thus the correct expression *is* divisible by $9$.

Comment: Oh my... Damn it. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Do you agree that $\,a(b+c)=ab+ac\,$? Well, this is just what happened here:

$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=[(n+1)(n+2)]\cdot n+[(n+1)(n+2)]\cdot 3$$

which is exactly what's written there.

**Added:** As for the other exercise:

$$10^{n+1}+3\cdot 4^{n+3}+5=10\cdot 10^n+4\cdot 3\cdot 4^{n+2}+5=$$

$$=\left(10^n+3\cdot 4^{n+2}+5\right)+9\cdot 10^n+3\cdot 3\cdot 4^{n+2}$$

and the first parentheses above is divisible by 9 by the inductive hypotheses, whereas the rest is *obviously* divisible by 9 as well!

Answer (score 0):

product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$

$n,(n+1),(n+2) $ are the three consecutive integers.then , it's product is divisible by $3!=6$

please see the proof of my statement

[The product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n$ factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)