# Prove or disprove that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$, without using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove or disprove that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$, without using induction

I have no idea how to go about this.

I should add that n is an integer. I started by looking for some  integer that was a single case disproving it, but I couldn't find one.

Any help/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211121/show-that-n3-n-is-divisible-by-6-using-induction). Several other candidates for duplicate targets can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%246%5Cmid%20n%5E3-n%24&p=1). That is the oldest (and has been used earlier as well).

Comment: This question is different than that possible duplicate: I'm trying to prove this without using induction

Comment: [Here's a variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202868/11619) where induction is not used. Sorry about not paying attention.

Comment: $$n^3-n = 6\binom{n+1}{3}\in 6\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 10):

We have
$$n^3 - n = n(n^2-1) = n(n+1)(n-1)$$

One of these $(n, n+1, n-1)$ must be even (why?) and one must be divisible by 3 (why?).

Comment: I can prove one of those must be even, but I'm not sure how to prove that one of them must be divisible by 3...

Comment: $n-1, n, n+1$ are three consecutive numbers. Whenever you have three consecutive numbers and take it $\pmod 3$, then one has to be $0 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

By the division theorem we have $n=6k+r$ for some $0 \le r < 6$. Then
$$(n^3-n) = (6k+r)^3 - (6k+r) = 6(x-k) + (r^3-r)$$
where $x = \sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{3}{i} 6^{i-1}k^ir^{3-i} \in \mathbb{Z}$ by the binomial theorem.

But $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, so $r^3-r \in \{0,0,6,24,60,120\}$, each of which is a multiple of $6$.

---

*Disclaimer: I would argue that both this answer and twnly's answer 'use induction', because both depend on results that themselves require induction in some form to be proved.*

Comment: That disclaimer is so, so true. You really can't do much with regards to the natural numbers without induction. In some definitions of natural numbers, induction is actually part of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Fermat's theorem and Chinese remainder theorem.